# PHP 5.6 - Function is_dir() Permissions Issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to scan folders recursively and store every *.h file found's path into an array.

```
function findfiles($input, &$array){
    $dir = scandir($input);

    foreach($dir as $file)
    {   
        if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..")
        {
            if (is_file(realpath($file)) && substr($file, -2) === ".h")
            {
                array_push($array, realpath($file));
            }

            if (is_dir(realpath($file)) //I'M EVEN USING ABSOLUTE PATH
            {
                findfiles(realpath($file), $array); 
            }
        }
    }
}

$input="./"
$array = array();
findfiles($input, $array);
```

I guess this should work but function is_dir() returns FALSE for directories "./atest/AA" and "./atest/FolderInside" even if I have all permissions set.

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 úno 14 18:46 AA
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 úno 14 15:12 FolderInside
```

and works great with other folders "atest" and "test1" even they have the same permissions set.

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    0 úno 14 18:46 atest
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    0 úno 14 15:39 test1
```

Please why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you cannot use just `$file` when calling `is_file()` or `is_dir()`, because it would search the file in `include_path` (possibly also in current directory). The correct way would be to prepend filename with pathname:

```
function findfiles($input, &$array){
    if (substr($input, -1) !== '/')
        $input .= '/';
    $dir = scandir($input);

    foreach($dir as $file)
    {   
        if ($file !== "." && $file !== "..")
        {
            if (is_file($input.$file) && substr($input.$file, -2) === ".h")
            {
                array_push($array, realpath($input.$file));
            }

            if (is_dir($input.$file))
            {
                findfiles($input.$file, $array); 
            }
        }
    }
}

$input="./";
$array = [];
findfiles($input, $array);
```

Comment: I modified wrong line of my code. Actually I'm using realpath($file) which returns full path of the file. Could you please take a look now and tell me if is it still bad ? I think I don't have to use your method but thank you very much for your response.

Comment: `realpath` is of no use in your code, because `scandir` returns only a list of filenames, without paths. And `realpath` cannot possible determine from which directory the `file.h` comes... So if it not present in the current directory, it will just return `false`.